# Dates disappear on 'Edit'

Tags: 6

[image]We are still on Drupal 6 which has worked fine for years, and I have not done any updates.
We have Date/Time boxes on our "Events" items with pop-up boxes (see image).
But since recently the when you 'Edit' an event the dates/times go blank, but they didn't use to.
We've done nothing to alter the setup at all!

It is not only annoying, but as the 'Front Page' is set to Chronological order, if the date is blank the event disappears (past it's date presumably), so the author can't even see it to notice & correct it!

There is another question similar "when using Scheduler......"
The only answer was "it must be a bug - report it"  BUT it used to work fine, and we have not changed or updated anything (I don't know how to!)
Apart from this the site works fine!

I am not a Drupal programmer so don't ask me to update any code!
I presume it must be a 'setting' somewhere, or could it be to do with lack of memory????

one image is date/time boxes as they appear on editing, the other image is how they look when the event is first posted (or when dates re-entered)

Mike

[image: Typical Date/Time boxes]

Comment: I Posted this under Scheduler, but could it be the WYSIWYG editor playing up???

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at yoursite.ca/admin/build/themes/settings.

When there, check that under "Display post information on" that your content type is checked.

After looking at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2230167), it seems like a bug in the date module. Try updating the date module, but **make sure** that you have a **backup** of the site before doing so.

You should also soon upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8, as Drupal 6 sites risked being hacked.

Comment: That seems to be just the "submitted by Username on date text" not the Event Date.

Comment: Oh, okay. Could you post screenshot of the edit display of the date field?

Comment: Here is a screen-shot as soon as you open it to edit, the picture above is view just before edit.   ..... I can't find how to add an image here!

Comment: @MikeDavies You can't add image in comments. Please update post with the screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, found that - added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is the likely culprit: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1808416

PHP version 5.4 and above caused some issues with the Date module in Drupal 6 that appear to match your symptoms.

The changes in the patch in comment #19 are probably what is needed.

This change should be included in the 2.10 release.

I would also recommend upgrading to Drupal 7 or 8 as soon as you can for security and longevity.

Hope this helps!

Finn